# The values from the list doesn't work in the function

Tags: python, list, function

I don't understand why I can't calculate the average value from the list.

When I put the values for this function in `print`, it works.

When I use `print` for `sum` and `len` from list `a`, it works.

But when I try to substitute values from a list into my function, it doesn't work.

I don't understand why.

```
a = [1000,2000]
def avrage_value_kcl_per_day(kcl,day):
    avkpd = kcl//day
    print(avkpd)

print('{}'.format(len(a)))

print('{}'.format(sum(a)))

print(avrage_value_kcl_per_day(3000,2))

print(avrage_value_kcl_per_day(('{}'.format(sum(a))),('{}'.format(len(a)))))
```

Comment: your function doesn't `return` anything. I presume it should return `avkpd`.

Comment: format makes a string, so you can't use it as a number, unless you convert it back

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, it just prints the average.

Comment: You're not passing the values to your function, you are passing string representations of the values to the function. Just don't do that. You don't need to use `format` in this code at all, not even for `print`, as it automatically converts values to strings.

Comment: When you say `it doesn't work`, you should update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: `avrage_value_kcl_per_day(sum(a), len(a))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing stuff in the body of the function itself, just simply call it. Next problem is that u have passed string values to the function in the last statement, when its job involves // of two numbers.

```
a = [1000,2000]
def avrage_value_kcl_per_day(kcl,day):
    avkpd = kcl//day
    print(avkpd)

print('{}'.format(len(a))) 

print('{}'.format(sum(a)))

avrage_value_kcl_per_day(3000,2)

avrage_value_kcl_per_day(sum(a), len(a)))
```

If u r on python 3, u can simply avoid format function & use an f string like `print(f'{len(a)}')`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `statistics.mean` instead of implementing your own `average` function:

```
from statistics import mean

a = [1000,2000]

print(len(a))
print(sum(a))
print(mean(a))
```

If you did need to define your own `average` function, it should take an iterable as the argument and return the average value (not print it):

```
a = [1000,2000]

def average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)


print(len(a))
print(sum(a))
print(average(a))
```